# Accessing an Ember-cli model class from a service

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying define a Person class within an Ember-cli project which I can then call from within a service. I've got a basic service working that updates when various inputs are changed but I can't reference the Person class at all. This is what I currently have:

```
# app/models/person.js 

import Ember from "ember";

var Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  helloWorld: function() {
    alert("Hi, my name is " + this.get('name'));
  }
});

export default Person;
```

and in the router I've got:

```
# app/router.js

import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';
import Person from './models/person';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  model: function() {
    return Person.create({
      name: "Tom Dale"
    });
  }
});
```

I'm pretty sure it's referenced the "import Person" correctly because if it's wrong I see an error about the file not being found.

then in the service I've got:

```
# /app/services/calculator.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({

  init: function () {

    // this gives "Person is not defined"
    const person = new Person();

    // this gives "Person is not defined"
    const person = Person.create({ name: "Tom Jones" });

    // this gives "store not defined" 
    const person = this.store.createRecord('person', { name: "Tom Jones" });

  },
});
```

Any pointers on how I can access the Person class from the service would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to address what I think are some misunderstandings.

First off, you have a Person class but it isn't a `DS.Model` so you won't be able to use it through Ember Data (`this.store`).

Your `router.js` file is where you define your routes, [as shown in the guides](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/routing/defining-your-routes/). You seem to be confusing it with how to [specify a route's model](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/)? Pay close attention to the file paths in the code samples.

As for the service, `Person` is not defined because unlike your `router.js` code, you are not importing `Person` into the module. Imports are per-module, so you also need `import Person from './models/person';` in your service. Check [jsmodules.io](http://jsmodules.io/) for more information.
Ember Data's store is injected into `Route`s and `Controllers` only, that's why `this.store` is undefined in the `Service`. If you want to access the store, do the following:

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(),

  init() {
    const person = this.get('store').createRecord('person', { name: "Tom Jones" });
  }
});
```

Mind you, the above **should not work** with the code you posted as `Person` isn't a `DS.Model`

Comment: Thanks for the insights. It was getting the class imported that was the main issue, and it eventually worked using:
import Person from '../models/person';
Just doing ./ meant it looked in app/services/models/person.js but I'd got it in app/models/person.js

Answer (score 1):

You need to import Person in **every** file that references it.

Add `import Person from './models/person';` to your service class.

Comment: Thanks - that's pretty much what the issue was. However, I've accepted the other answer because they suggested it first.